# Dividing Audio signals into Barks Bands

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft, spectrum, audio-fingerprinting

I want to apply the following steps in matlab

1) Read the audio data

2) Apply window function on that data

3) Apply fft on the result of window function

4) Make power spectrum of fft

5) divide power spectrum in Barks bands

```
[y,Fs,bits] = wavread('file1.wav');
Nsamps = length(y);
ham= hamming(Nsamps);
ham_fft = abs(fft(ham));
ham_fft = ham_fft(1:Nsamps/2);      %Discard Half of Points
plot(f, ham_fft,f1)
xlim([0 1000])  
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
ylabel('Amplitude')
title('FFT of Hamming Window of  a an audio');
```

I am not getting the correct waveform , want to draw the spectrum and then Divide into barks bands .

Comment: You don't seem to be applying the window function to your audio data `y` here

Comment: Duplicate http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/18565/dividing-audio-signals-into-barks-bands